# Json: the remote server returned an error (500) internal server error

Tags: json, winforms, web-services

i am trying to read a web service in Json format

here is my code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        var data = wc.DownloadString(JsonUri);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data));
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<PaymentMethod>));
        var result = serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
```

i get an error on this line:

```
var data = wc.DownloadString(JsonUri);
```

the JsonUri is : http://avaris.kwekud.com/api/v1/items/uniqueitem/?username=joel&api_key=959dd41efd06b84ca7f10b1b12f5f3e6567c07dc&format=json

Any Help

thanks

Comment: Under what conditons does the 500 error occur? Clearly not in response to a simple query (at least, not right now; it's entirely possible for servers to get overwhelmed).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when i try the link i added bellow , i received the response in the output format.

Comment: @ Djama: They may be blocking/rate-limiting your IP or similar, possibly because you're repeatedly making an invalid request. When I try it, I get this: http://pastie.org/8670231 That opens with `"error_message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'workspace'"`...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: have you tried it using the link i provided bellow ?

Comment: @ Djama: "Below" where? I used the one above, in your question, obviously.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks , you are really lovely :)

Comment: @ Djama: ?? I'm not following.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem in the python code on the server that is returning the API.  A good idea is to try to make the call from outside of your code to make sure that it is not your code.  Any packet sniffing tool eg firebug in firefox will be able to tell you if the call is going wrong pr its your code being badly formed.

It looks like the API is currently broken, so you should put a try ... catch in there and handle the exception for situations like this:

[image]